# Setting a class function to a pointer in constructor C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constructor

I have a class that I want to have a default function to be pointed to when constructing without parameters, but I want that functionality to change when a function is passed in with one of the parameters.

I'm getting the error "a value of type "int (MyClass::*)(int myVar)" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "MyClass::funcptr""
but it seems like the defaultFunction should match the definition to the function pointer.
I fought with this for a while and I'm having trouble understanding what the issue is here.
Any Help is appreciated.

--MyClass.h--

```
class MyClass{
    private:
        typedef int (*funcptr)(const int myVar);
        funcptr myfuncptr;
        int defaultFunc(int myVar);
    public:
        MyClass(funcptr functionpointer);
        MyClass();
        void callFunction(int myVar);
        
};
```

--MyClass.cpp--

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
    myfuncptr = defaultFunc; //a value of type "int (MyClass::*)(int myVar)" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "MyClass::funcptr"

};

MyClass::MyClass(funcptr functionpointer){
    myfuncptr = functionpointer;
};

void MyClass::callFunction(int myVar){
    int i = (*myfuncptr)(myVar);

};
int MyClass::defaultFunc(int myVar){
    return myVar + 3;
};
```

Comment: `funcptr` is a pointer-to-function. `&MyClass::defaultFunc` (not the raw `defaultFunc`, which is an error except with Microsoft's non-conforming compiler) is a pointer-to-member-function. They're not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what felt like every combination of function pointer typedefs and using but in the end I think that lambda is what worked. Thanks everyone for the help.

--MyClass.h--

```
class MyClass{
    private:
        std::function<int(int)> func;
        int defaultFunc(int myVar);
    public:
        MyClass(std::function<bool(int)> func);
        MyClass();
        void callFunction(int myVar);
        
};
```

--MyClass.cpp--

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
    this->func = [=] (int a) {return defaultFunc(a);};

};

MyClass::MyClass(std::function<int(int)> func;){
    this->func = func;
};

void MyClass::callFunction(int myVar){
    int i = func(myVar);

};
int MyClass::defaultFunc(int myVar){
    return myVar + 3;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it into

```cpp
        typedef std::function<int(int)> funcptr;
```

(btw `using` is more idiomatic than `typedef` these days) and

```cpp
myfuncptr = [this](int x){ return defaultFunc(x); };
```